# Merging Pandas styler object side by side

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I have two styler (pandas styler) objects , lets say s1 and s2 ( i want to merge s1 and s2 side by side). In pandas 1.5 there is a support for styler object by using concat (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.concat.html) but there is no option for merging side by side . can anyone help on this?**[your text](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)**

I am writing a recurring function which creates styler objects , wanted the styler objects merge side by side so that i will have single styler object with all the stylings merged side by side.

```
for each_col in colouring_columns:
    threshold_list2=colouring_columns[each_col]
    print(threshold_list2)
    mod_stat_columns2 = aggregated_value + "(" + each_col + ")"
    print(mod_stat_columns2)
    print(final_df.columns)
    print(common_columns)
    mod_stat_columns3=[]
    mod_stat_columns3.extend(common_columns)
    print(mod_stat_columns3)
    mod_stat_columns3.append(mod_stat_columns2)
    print(mod_stat_columns3)


    print(mod_stat_columns3)
    individual_colouring_df=final_df[mod_stat_columns3]

    styler_object2=individual_colouring_df.reset_index(drop=True).style.set_properties(**{
                                                                  "border": "1px solid black",
                                                                  "border-collapse": "collapse",
                                                                  "border-color":"black",
                                                                  "padding": "5px",

                                                                  }).set_table_styles([{
                                                                        'selector': 'th',
                                                                        'props': [('border', '1px black solid !important')]}]).applymap(add_color,subset=mod_stat_columns2,threshold=threshold_list2,operator=aggregated_value).format(precision=2)

    print(styler_object2)
    if (isinstance(styler_object,pd.io.formats.style.Styler)):
        **styler_object=styler_object2.concat(styler_object, axis =0)**
        print("in combine")
    else:
        styler_object=styler_object2
        print("in single")
```

the merge should be side by side , right now was not able to solve it

Comment: `Styler.concat` only works in vertical mode. If you want to combine horizontally you must first combine the underlying `DataFrame` and then create a single `Styler` of that merged dataframe.

Comment: Here my requirement is each column should be colored based on different thresholds for each column , so i was making styler object for each column and thought of combining, if you have some has better idea on how to apply styling on each column separately and then have that object, i wanted a dynamic code ,as  i dont want to use static one line code where applying applymap function in one single static code.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the next solution:

You need to declare the following styler statement:

```
styler1.set_table_attributes("style='display:inline'")
styler2.set_table_attributes("style='display:inline'")
```

and then display the two stylers:

```
display_html(styler1._repr_html_()+styler2._repr_html_(), raw=True)
```